# How can I change this div layout so that the float works in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<div class="sectiuni_home_box" style="width: 626px; padding-left: 0px;">
    <div class="sectiuni_home_box_t" style="border-left: 0; width: 618px;">
        <div class="sectiuni_home_box_v" style=" width: 616px;">
            <div align="left" style="width: 1px; border: 0; border-left: 1px solid #c3c3c3; float:left; height: 100%; padding: 0; vertical-align: middle;"></div>
            <div id="actiuni" name="actiuni">
                <table style="border: 0;"></table>
                <div id="lista_actiuni" name="lista_actiuni">
                    <div id="actiuni_scroll" class="scroll" style="width: 100%; height: 428px; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
       </div>
   </div>
```

This is the layout i'm talking about. the only div that has the float is suppsoed to be to the left of #actiuni and #lista_actiuni. Looks exactly like that in Firefox, but IE puts #lista_actiuni below everything else. It puts the float div to the left, the table to the right of it starting at the top but then when it's time to place #lista_actiuni it drops it all the way down to where the floaty div ends. To make it worse it sometimes corrects itself and places everything nicely, only to be broken again when I switch pages or refresh.

Any ideas on what could be causing it?

I've scrapped together a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/u5WwU/5/) using code from the page. Closest thing I can get. The problem is that in the example it looks wrong both in ie and in Firefox but on the actual website it works corectly.

edit: edited the jsfiddle, replaced with a version that works properly in Firefox yet fails in IE.

update: it seems removing the #actiuni_scroll div and the table within it and leaving only the bare data i've managed to make it display properly so my guess is that's where the problem is

update 2: I've fixed the problem by removing the width attribute from the #actiuni_scroll div. It seems firefox know how to calculate the 100% width to include the elements floated to its left but IE doesn't.

Comment: Can you link to the page? It would make this much easier to answer.

Comment: It requires a login and actual data in order to see the problem, also we haven't inject-proofed anything yet so i'm reluctant to do that. I could post some screen caps.

Comment: In that case, the next best thing would be if you could create an accurate [demonstration of the problem](http://jsbin.com/). Screenshots probably won't help much.

Comment: @Bogdan Alternatively, you can use http://JSFiddle.net ; point in case is, we can't guess, need the CSS as well, and if you want people to understand the problem you must enable them to reproduce it.

Comment: I'll try to replicate the problem in JSFiddle and post it up here, might even find the problem trough it. wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Added the jsfiddle demonstration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by removing the width attribute from the #actiuni_scroll div. It seems firefox know how to calculate the 100% width to include the elements floated to its left but IE doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Completely off the top of my head (without anything visual to play with) I reckon you could try adding `overflow:hidden` to the `.sectiuni_home_box_v` div.

Answer (score 0):

Floats need to be cleared, it does not look like you are doing this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sectiuni_home_box_v">

<!-- IE6 has problems with more than 1 css rule & IE7 does not recognise psudeo's SO -->
<br class=clearfix />

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clearfix{
     clear:both;
     visibility: hidden;
     height:0;
     *zoom:1;
    }
```

> NOTE: IE7 will apply double margin to some elements and in some cases
>   double padding, you can do a quick fix with a css rule {
>   *display:inline;*zoom:1; }

Comment: I'm trying this on IE9, also I don't understand what the fix you're proposing does or where I should stick it.

Comment: <div class="sectiuni_home_box">  //your content here...   <br class=clearfix /> </div>

Comment: that did nothing but add an empty line at the end of the div. Check the jsfiddle demonstration if you want a live example. It works great on firefox, but doesn't on IE.

Comment: because you didnt add the css rule, did you?